# grunt-angular-builder "Ignored File"

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am experiencing something strange when running grunt-angular. For some reasons it is seeing files however ignoring them when running the command `grunt release -v'. the result is:

```
Running "angular-builder:app" (angular-builder) task
Verifying property angular-builder.app exists in config...OK
Files: app/components/home/homeController.js, app/core/app.js -> build/admin_tools.js
Options: mainModule="AdminTools"
Reading app/components/home/homeController.js...OK
Ignored file: app/components/home/homeController.js

Generating the release build...

Not optimizing anchorScrollOffsetExample because it shares some/all of its files with other modules.
Including module ngRoute.
Scanning ngRoute for non-angular script dependencies...
Validating app/core/angular-route.js...OK
Including module AdminTools.
Scanning AdminTools for non-angular script dependencies...
Validating app/core/app.js...OK
Writing build/admin_tools.js...OK

Done, without errors.
```

As you can see there is a js file called `homController.js` which it sees, but then ignores it and I can't figure out why. The contents of that file is.

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log){

    doThis = function(){
        alert('Hello There');
    }

}]);
```

Pretty simple stuff. The app.js looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('AdminTools', ['ngRoute']);   

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider 
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

-- EDIT Adding Grunt File --

```
module.exports = function (grunt){

    grunt.initConfig ({

        'angular-builder': {
            options: {
                mainModule: 'AdminAdmin'
            },
            app: {
                src:  'app/**/*.js',
                dest: 'build/admin_tools.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks ('grunt-angular-builder');

    grunt.registerTask ('default', ['angular-builder']);
    grunt.registerTask ('release', ['angular-builder']);
    grunt.registerTask ('debug', ['angular-builder::debug']);

};
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: you are using grunt right? can you paste gruntfile then?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem. It had to do with the way I was modularizing the app.

The controller needed to be:

```
angular.module('home.controller', [])
    .controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log){

        doThis = function(){
            alert('Hello There');
        }

}]);
```

with the app.js registering the dependency like so.

```
angular.module('AdminTools', [
    'ngRoute',
    'home.controller']);  

angular.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider 
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```